# Concentration of solutions

Tags: concentration

I'm stuck with this problem. If I have 200 grams of a solution at 30% how much water should I add so that the concentration becomes 25%?

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.‎

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that for a simple dilution the following formula applies:

$$c_1m_1 = c_2m_2$$ $$ m_2 = \frac{c_1m_1}{c_2} = \frac{(200g)(30\text{%})}{20\text{%}} = 240g$$

Therefore the mass to add is $(240g - 200g) = 40g$ of $\ce{H2O}$ (which is 40 ml of $\ce{H2O}$).

Comment: I would +1 if you added units wherever it was necessary.

Comment: Agreed - A unit analysis is always right to be sure you're getting what you think you are getting.

Comment: It's a homework question - they shouldn't be answered with exact calculation

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule for. In german wikipedia there is a article for 'Mischkreuz', I don't know the equivalent in english, maybe the 'cross over rule'.

If you have two solutions with different concentrations and have to mix up a concentration in the middle. The difference between the start concentrations and the final concentration gives the volume ratio of the input solutions.

In your example:

You need 25 parts of your concentrated solution. (difference: 25% - 0%)

And 5 parts of water. (difference: 30% - 25%)